# Programming a MMO server for cross platform mobile clients

Tags: java, ios, client, cross-platform

I'm working on a small MMO project that run on android, iOS, j2me, window phone. I already built a java server and a working android project. now i'm facing problems with the other platforms. Some of my common libraries (include by both client and server) written on java (1.6) cannot run on j2me ( maybe iOS and window phone neither).

Server <--->handled by common libraries<-----packet--->handled by common libraries---> client

So, how can I make the server working with all platform??

I'm just a junior programmer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the server return common formats responses, such as JSON and XML. Then each client can parse it and use it. Or you can communicate via sockets, but you won't be able to reuse much code, especially since iOS development uses Obj-C, Windows Phone uses C# and Android uses Java (which may be different from Java ME).

Comment: Upvote for JSON - XML can be much more verbose which is not what you need when you go mobile. I'd just add REST over SOAP any day